# Sql Server 2014 - Rows to Columns convert Dynamically-

Tags: sql-server-2014, pivot

Below are my query and table details

```
create table #ReviewData
(
 ProjectId int,
 ReviewId int,
 ReviewDataPointKey varchar(max),
 ReviewDataPointValue varchar(max))

 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_FacilityTypeId', 'Hospital_Inpatient')

 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_FacilityTypeId', 'Hospital_Inpatient_Other')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F11.14', 'F11.14_text')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F11.15', 'F11.15_text')



 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F12.16', 'F12.16_text')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F12.17', 'F12.17_text')

  Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterStartDate', '11/04/2019')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterEndDate', '11/04/2019')



 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterStartDate', '11/08/2019')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterEndDate', '11/08/2019')

  Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisPageNumber', '3')

   Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisPageNumber', '5')


  Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_ProviderCredential', 'Sample')

   Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_ProviderCredential', 'Testing')

     Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_3_DiagnosisCode_F12.16', 'F12.16_text')

   Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_3_DiagnosisCode_F12.17', 'F12.17_text')

        Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_3_FacilityTypeId', 'OutPatient')

                Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_4_FacilityTypeId', 'OutPatient_Other')

              Insert into #ReviewData values (1,73,'SaasEncounter_4_ProviderCredential', 'New')



 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_FacilityTypeId', 'Physician_InPatient')

 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_FacilityTypeId', 'Physician_InPatient_Other')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F10.14', 'F10.14_text')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F10.15', 'F10.15_text')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F20.16', 'F20.16_text')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F20.17', 'F20.17_text')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F25.14', 'F25.14_text')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F35.15', 'F35.15_text')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F45.16', 'F45.16_text')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F65.17', 'F65.17_text')

   Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterStartDate', '11/04/2019')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterEndDate', '11/04/2019')



 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterStartDate', '11/08/2019')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterEndDate', '11/08/2019')


 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,902,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterStartDate', '11/08/2019')



 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,902,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterEndDate', '11/11/2019')

  Insert into #ReviewData values (1,902,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterStartDate', '11/05/2019')

 Insert into #ReviewData values (1,902,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterEndDate', '11/08/2019')
```

```
 Select * from #ReviewData where ProjectId = 1
```

```
 select
    rd.ProjectId, 
    rd.ReviewId, 
    rdpv.ReviewDataPointValue as FacilityType,
    rdpv3.ReviewDataPointValue as DiagnosisCode,
    rdpv1.ReviewDataPointValue as EncounterStartDate,
    rdpv2.ReviewDataPointValue as EncounterEndDate,
    rdpv4.ReviewDataPointValue as DiagnosisPageNumber,
    rdpv5.ReviewDataPointValue as ProviderCredential
from
    #ReviewData rd JOIN Project P ON P.ProjectId = 1 and rd.ProjectId = 1
    JOIN Client C ON C.ClietId = P.ClientId 
cross apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd2
     where  rd2.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd2.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd2.ReviewDataPointKey like '%FacilityTypeId%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd2.ReviewDataPointKey, '_FacilityTypeId', '%')

            ) rdpv
            cross apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd2
     where  rd2.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd2.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd2.ReviewDataPointKey like '%EncounterStartDate%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd2.ReviewDataPointKey, '_EncounterStartDate', '%')

            ) rdpv1
                        cross apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd2
     where  rd2.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd2.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd2.ReviewDataPointKey like '%EncounterEndDate%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd2.ReviewDataPointKey, '_EncounterEndDate', '%')

            ) rdpv2
                                    cross apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd2
     where  rd2.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd2.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd2.ReviewDataPointKey like '%DiagnosisCode%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd2.ReviewDataPointKey, '_DiagnosisCode', '%')

            ) rdpv3
                                                cross apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd3
     where  rd3.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd3.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd3.ReviewDataPointKey like '%DiagnosisPageNumber%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd3.ReviewDataPointKey, '_DiagnosisPageNumber', '%')

            ) rdpv4
                                                cross apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd4
     where  rd4.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd4.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd4.ReviewDataPointKey like '%ProviderCredential%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd4.ReviewDataPointKey, '_ProviderCredential', '%')

            ) rdpv5

where
    rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%FacilityTypeId%'and
        rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%EncounterStartDate%' and
         rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%EncounterEndDate%' and 
                 rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%ProviderCredential%' and 
                         rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%ProviderCredential%' and 

         rd.ProjectId = 1
```

My Current Output

[image]

My Expected Output

[image]

Kindly help me to get Expected Output

Answer (score -1):

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=bf4e7b53902ab0db1ab3e76c2c93895b)

You are doing a `CROSS APPLY` on a value that only exists for `ReviewId=73`, and not for other `ReviewId`. You will only see results If the query after the cross apply will return at least 1 record.

And you did to this: `JOIN Project P ON P.ProjectId = 1 and rd.ProjectId = 1`
I think `JOIN Project P ON P.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId` was your intention?

You can change the `CROSS APPLY` to a `LEFT JOIN`, see this [dbfidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=732fcb5de7cf13798d4af26ec4d37bf4)

For an (simple) example of how you can rewrite a `CROSS APPLY` to a `LEFT JOIN` is in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=00411d51d50c9884a623e354db685677)